# How does currying work with lambdas in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, currying

Just looking at learn you a Haskell (great work) and under the section [curried functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions) there is an example that says the following two functions are the same:

```
addThree x y z = x + y + z  
addThree = \x -> \y -> \z -> x + y + z
```

What confuses me here is how currying is applied to lambda(s).
With the type of the function being

```
addThree :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a -> a
```

When lambdas are used is the function equal to `\x -> (\y -> (\z -> x + y + z))` ?
If this is the case, then is `x + y` treated as a constant in the innermost lambda? That is, `\z -> c + z` where `c` is `x + y` ?

Comment: You should start with reading about [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When reading type signatures like `addThree :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a` you should mentally add in the appropriate parentheses as arrows right associate

```
addThree :: Num a => a ->  a ->  a -> a
addThree :: Num a => a -> (a -> (a -> a))
```

which perhaps helps to describe how single-argument lambdas are sufficient to represent a function like this.

When talking about curried lambdas, you can look at things from a few directions. Let's examine that inner fragment, for instance

```
\z -> x + y + z
```

If that were all you were given and asked to interpret it, you'd have to throw your hands up in frustration—there's no definition at all for what `x` and `y` should mean. They are known as "free" variables because they are not constrained by the lambda.

In order to give them definition, we must wrap more lambdas which *bind* meaning to `x` and `y`.

```
\x -> \y ->     \z -> x + y + z       -- ok!
```

So, looking from the inside out, the expression is meaningless without those outer lambdas.

However, as you begin to evaluate the expression under application

```
(\x -> \y -> \z -> x + y + z) 1 2 3
```

then a different story emerges. Now, you must handle each lambda binding entirely on its own. The rule is that in order to evaluate a lambda being applied to a value, you substitute the bound variable for that value everywhere inside of it.

```
(\x -> \y -> \z -> x + y + z) 1 2
(      \y -> \z -> 1 + y + z)   2
(            \z -> 1 + 2 + z)
```

So, from the outside, the expression `\z -> x + y + z` never exists, the `x` and `y` are eliminated before we get that far.

It's worth noting, however, that this is not quite the same as `c + z` still! We do not evaluate the body of the inner lambda prior to binding the third argument. There's, in some sense, no way to know what's inside a lambda until we give it some value; `(\z -> 1 + 2 + z)` is completely opaque. Only once the final argument has been applied can we begin to evaluate the addition inside the body.

Broadly this is what's known as the difficulty of working "underneath a binder".

Comment: `:i (+)` ==> `infixl 6 +` ==> no such thing as `\x y z -> x + y + z`, only `\x y z -> (x + y) + z` which a compiler is free/practically has to rewrite/implement as `\x y z -> let c=x+y in c + z`... one could reasonably expect.

Comment: Agreed, though that has more to do with the evaluation steps for `(1 + 2) + 3` than the semantics of a lambda, though. If `(\z -> (1 + 2) + z)` never gets applied then no matter what happens under the lambda it's immaterial.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The point about c is a bit complicated. I know it is not evaluated but but when the inner most lambda is evaluated c is guaranteed to be 1 + 2. Would 'bound variables' instead of constant be a better definition here?

Comment: Yes, `c` is guaranteed to be `(1 + 2)` once application has occurred, but by the time evaluation occurs `z := 3` (or whatever value is applied) so there's not a difference between `(x + y)` and `z` anymore—they've all been substituted to concrete values so the evaluation order now depends on `(+)`, not lambda. The term "bound variable" refers to the difference between `x` and `z` in `\z -> x + z`—`x` is "free" because it has to be determined by something in the ambient environment while `z` is bound because it's described locally.